# Трехмерный массив, где каждый элемент равен своему индексу

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

Только начал изучать Java. Решил сделать многомерный массив, где каждый элемент равен своему индексу: `arr[0][0][0] = 0; arr[1][2][2] = 5`.

```
int[][][] arr = new int[5][2][3];
int s = 0;
int t = 0;
for (int f = 0; f < arr.length; f++) {
    while (s < 2) {
        while (t < 3) {
            arr[f][s][t] = f + s + t;
            System.out.println(arr[f][s][t]);
            t++;
        }
        s++;
    }
    if (s == 2) {
        s = 0;
    }
    if (t == 3) {
        t = 0;
    }
}
```

Но на выходе имею вместо 30 элементов от 0 до 7 `arr[0][0][0] = 0, arr[4][1][2] = 7`, всего 15 элементов от 0 до 6. До этого я писал код для двухмерного массива подобным принципом, и он работал корректно.

Comment: Перенесите `if (t == 3) { ... }` в конец первого `while`. И почему бы вам не использовать for три раза, зачем извращаться?

Comment: Спасибо, про for не сразу подумал, а потом решил добить while, разобраться же во всем надо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Три вложенных цикла `for`:

  ```java
  int[][][] arr = new int[5][2][3];

  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
          for (int k = 0; k < arr[i][j].length; k++)
              arr[i][j][k] = i + j + k;

  // вывод
  for (int[][] a : arr)
      System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
  ```
- Три вложенных цикла `while`:

  ```java
  int[][][] arr = new int[5][2][3];

  int i = 0;
  while (i < arr.length) {
      int j = 0;
      while (j < arr[i].length) {
          int k = 0;
          while (k < arr[i][j].length) {
              arr[i][j][k] = i + j + k;
              k++;
          }
          j++;
      }
      i++;
  }

  // вывод
  for (int[][] a : arr)
      System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
  ```
- Вывод одинаковый в обоих случаях:

  ```
  [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
  [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
  [[2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
  [[3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]
  [[4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7]]
  ```